# How affect for each user a subdomain ?

Tags: users, subsites

with module domain-acces, we can  manage domains and subdomains,
example:

- domain.com is my first domain.
- user1.domain.com is affected to user1
- user2.domain.com is affected to user2

but user1 can connect to user2.domain.com that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like this isn't what Domain Access was intended to do, as its focus is "sharing information across subdomains" rather than restricting it:

https://www.drupal.org/project/domain/issues/480716

In the comments there is a link to a code library that can achieve what you want, however.

Comment: I need this module in core 8.x